# find orthonormal vectors $q_1,q_2$ in the subspace $Span\{a,b\}$ spanned by

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking to see if my workings so far are correct, and if so then help finding my next answer to question b). I need to find orthonormal vectors $q_1,q_2$ in the subspace $Span\{a,b\}$ spanned by $a=\begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\3
\\4  
\\5  
\\7
\end{bmatrix}$, $b=\begin{bmatrix}
-6 
\\6
\\8 
\\0
\\8
\end{bmatrix}$ of $R^5$. My logic here was to use the Gram–Schmidt process. So,

let $x_1 = a $ and $x_2=b$ so $q_1 = x_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\3
\\4  
\\5  
\\7
\end{bmatrix}$
then $q_2 = x_2 - proj_{q_1}x_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
-6 
\\6
\\8 
\\0
\\8
\end{bmatrix} - \frac{x_2q_1}{q_1q_1}q_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
-6 
\\6
\\8 
\\0
\\8
\end{bmatrix} - \frac{100}{100}\begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\3
\\4  
\\5  
\\7
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-7 
\\3
\\4  
\\-5 
\\1
\end{bmatrix}$ If this logic is correct which vector in the subspace is closest to  $\begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\0
\\0  
\\0  
\\0
\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: $\|q_1\|\ne1$. Your basis is orthogonal, but not orthonormal.

Comment: @amd how do I fix that then?

Comment: Normalize the two vectors, of course.

Comment: @amd okay so $q_1=  \frac{1}{10} \begin{bmatrix}
1  
\\3
\\4  
\\5  
\\7
\end{bmatrix}$ ???

Comment: That’s right. You’ll also seed to normalize $q_2$.

Comment: @amd okay so then $q_2 =  \frac{1}{10} \begin{bmatrix}
-7 
\\3
\\4  
\\-5 
\\1
\end{bmatrix}$?? but then what do I do from here?

Comment: Let $v$ be some vector in the span and $w=(1,0,0,0,0)^T$. Think about the angle that $v-w$ makes with $v$. What is this angle when $\|v-w\|$ is minimal? What does that tell you about $v$ relative to $w$?

Comment: @amd what Is w?

Comment: Reread the comment. It’s in there.

Comment: @amd so now I have solved for $q_1.q_2$ after normalizing right?

Comment: @amd I am not sure what angle $v-w$ with v, not quite sure how to get v

Comment: Think about it this way, then: how would you find the shortest distance from an arbitrary point in $\mathbb R^5$ to the space spanned by $a$ and $b$? Visualize it in three dimensions first: what’s the shortest distance between a plane and a point not on the plane?

Comment: @amd sorry I am not quite understanding why

Answer (score 1):

First off, $\|q_1\|\ne1$ and $\|q_2\|\ne1$, so you have an *orthogonal* basis instead of an *orthonormal* one, but that’s easily remedied: simply normalize the two vectors.

For the second part, think about a similar situation in $\mathbb R^3$. The shortest distance between a point $P$ and a plane is along a line that’s perpendicular to the plane, so the closest point on the plane to $P$ lies at the intersection of this perpendicular line and the plane. In vector terms, it’s the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto the plane. The same principle holds in higher dimensions. Since you’ve now got an orthonormal basis for the span of $a$ and $b$, computing this projection is a simple matter.